# New Contract Id from new asset in separate for loops

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement to Create contracts and assets from Opportunites and lineitems when the opp is closed

So far the logic works well, i am having issue linking the newly created assets with the contract

The contract and assets are created in separate for loops and i cannot get the id for the contract into the loop that is creating the assets

```
ass.Contract__c = newcontracts[0].id;
```

Trying to get the id from the list is the closet i have come as debug on the list shows the id, however this doesnt work

trigger

```
trigger CreateContracts on Opportunity (After Update) {



set<Id> oppIds = new set<id>();
map<id,opportunity> Accountid = New map<id,opportunity>();

for(Opportunity o : trigger.new){
    if(o.isWon && !trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).isWon){
        oppIds.add(o.Id);
        accountid.put(o.Id, o);
    }
}
list<Opportunity> myOpps = [Select Id, Name, StageName, OwnerId, AccountId, CloseDate, Amount
                                From Opportunity 
                                Where Id In : oppIds];

system.debug(myOpps);

list<Opportunitylineitem> myOppLines = [Select Id, opportunityid, product2id, unitprice,name
                                From Opportunitylineitem 
                                Where opportunityId In : oppIds];

//if(oppIds.size()>0){Id Account = [SELECT id,accountid From Opportunity where id IN : oppids].accountid;}

//System.debug(account);


list<Contract> newContracts = new list<Contract>();  
list<Asset> newAsset= new list<Asset>();  

for(Opportunity o : myOpps){
    Contract Con = New Contract();
    con.AccountId = o.AccountId;
    con.Status = 'Draft';




    newContracts.add(Con);
}

insert newContracts;

system.debug(newContracts);

//if contractid on opp isblank integer i = 0 while less that opp line size create asset for each line

For(Integer i = 0; i < myOppLines.size() ; i++){


  Asset Ass = New Asset();

  Ass.Product2Id = myOppLines[i].product2id;
  ass.Name = myOppLines[i].name;
  ass.AccountId = Accountid.get(myOppLines[i].opportunityid).accountid;
  ass.Contract__c = newcontracts[0].id;

  NewAsset.add(Ass);  

} 





    Insert NewAsset;

}
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between Contracts and Opptys?  But id separate these triggers out.. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns

Comment: though you have another good answer, check my approach just in case if you have other thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is tie the new `Contracts` being created to an `Id` that you can access from each `OpportunityLineItem`. A `Map` can help you accomplish this.

```
// Instead of creating a list to hold new Contracts, make it a map
// The key of the map can be something other than the Id of the Contract (which doesn't
//   exist at this point in time)
Map<Id, Contract> oppIdToContract = new Map<Id, Contract>();
for(Opportunity o : myOpps){
    Contract con = New Contract();
    con.AccountId = o.AccountId;
    con.Status = 'Draft';

    oppIdToContract.add(o.Id, con);
}

// We can't DML on a Map, but we can DML on the list returned by map.values()
// DML insert will cause the record instances passed to it to be updated with the 
//   Id after it finishes.
// Because .values() returns a list that contain references to the same in-memory
//   object instances that are stored in the map, this means that the Contract
//   records stored in the map will have their Id populated after the DML finishes.
insert oppIdToContract.values();

for(OpportunityLineItem oli :myOppLines){
    Asset ass = New Asset();

    // You queried OpportunityId for OpportunityLineItem, so we can use that to
    //   pull the corresponding Contract from our map.
    ass.ContractId = oppIdToContract.get(oli.OpportunityId).Id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Best way to handle this use case is to insert records based on ExternalId.

**With a single insert statement you could insert both Parent and Child records.**

Create an external Id field on Contract Object and insert Contract and Assets record in a single insert.

Here is the approach.

```
trigger CreateContracts on Opportunity (After Update) {

    //keep your existing code as it was upto this line

    Map<String,String> contractOpptyMap = new Map<String,String>(); //it will hold OpportunityId and ExternalId                         

    list<Contract> newContracts = new list<Contract>();  
    list<Asset> lstNewAsset= new list<Asset>();  

    //build records from Opportunities.
    for(Opportunity o : myOpps)
    {
        Contract con = New Contract();
        con.AccountId = o.AccountId;
        con.Status = 'Draft';
        con.External_Id__c = String.ValueOf(Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000)));
        contractOpptyMap.put(o.Id,con.External_Id__c);
        newContracts.add(Con);
    }

    //build records from Opportunity line items
    for(Integer i = 0; i < myOppLines.size() ; i++)
    {
        Asset AssetObj = New Asset();

        AssetObj.Product2Id = myOppLines[i].product2id;
        AssetObj.Name = myOppLines[i].name;
        AssetObj.AccountId = Accountid.get(myOppLines[i].opportunityid).accountid;

        //map the reference
        Contract conReference = new Contract(
        External_Id__c =contractOpptyMap.get(myOppLines[i].OpportunityId)); 
        AssetObj.Contract = conReference;

        lstNewAsset.add(AssetObj);  

    }

    SObject[] sobjList = new List<SObject>(); 
    sobjList.addAll(newContracts);
    sobjList.addAll(lstNewAsset);   
    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(sobjList);
}
```

> For more information, refer my blog post: [Insert Multiple Parent and Child Records with External Id](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/insert-multiple-parent-and-child.html)
>
> And [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) documentation